# How can i prevent my site from reloading on POST?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a form with a submit button and some text fields. 
Depending on what you type in the textfields the page should change its appereance but it reloads and all changes return to the defaults.

How can I make sure tha page does not reset? I'm just using HTML, CSS and js.

Comment: maybe e.preventDefault() ? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: You can use event.preventDefault(); But without seeing your code I can only tell you this

Comment: You will need to use ajax(or something similar) to make the POST request instead of form submit.

Answer (score 0):

A form reloads the page - use `preventDefault` to stop reloading, then use the Fetch API to POST:

```
form.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch("url", { method: "POST", body: formData });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may not be intending to do any ajax at all. If that is the case you can add `onsubmit="return false"` in the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best answer it Ajax call. Refer following link. You dont need to reload the page/ page doesnt reload until manual reload.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp